# Can't set scoring parameter to 'neg_mean_squared_error' in cross_val_score

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm working on a regression problem, and I am evaluating my model using cross_val_score. I am trying to predict car prices based on some features.

I'm trying to set the 'scoring' parameter to 'neg_mean_squared_error', but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [46], line 1
----> 1 cross_val_score(model, transformed_X, y, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Code that gave the error:

```
cross_val_score(model, transformed_X, y, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```

transformed_X contains categorical features that have been one-hot-encoded. y are labels (price values for the cars). Code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

OneHotEncoder = OneHotEncoder()
categorical_features = ["Make", "Colour", "Doors"]
transformer = ColumnTransformer([("one-hot",
                                   OneHotEncoder,
                                   categorical_features)],
                                   remainder="passthrough")

transformed_X = transformer.fit_transform(X)
transformed_X

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

np.random.seed(0)

X = car_sales.drop("Price", axis=1)
y = car_sales["Price"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(transformed_X,
                                                    y,
                                                    test_size=0.2)

model = RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.score(X_test, y_test)

cross_val_score(model, transformed_X, y, cv=5, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error')
```

This is an example of transformed_X (it is an array of floats):

```
array([[0.0000000e+00, 1.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 3.5431000e+04,
        4.3200000e+02, 2.2015860e+04],
       [1.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 1.9271400e+05,
        1.0300000e+02, 1.1974723e+05],
       [0.0000000e+00, 1.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 8.4714000e+04,
        3.3400000e+02, 5.2638970e+04],
       ...,
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 1.0000000e+00, ..., 6.6604000e+04,
        4.7300000e+02, 4.1385910e+04],
       [0.0000000e+00, 1.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 2.1588300e+05,
        1.8000000e+01, 1.3414381e+05],
       [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 2.4836000e+05,
        5.1000000e+01, 1.5432413e+05]])
```

If I run np.mean(cross_val_score(model, transformed_X, y, cv=5)) without the scoring parameter, it works normally.

I searched online, and the answers I saw don't really answer my question.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes what other information should I add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this. This feels like a "*Jupyter notebook out-of-order cell execution bug*."

If you're trying to combine a column transformer + one-hot encoding + Random Forests + cross validation + negative mean squared error, you're probably looking for this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

# Generate fake dataset with three numeric features and a categorical column
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000, n_features=3)
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=["A", "B", "C"])
df["D"] = ["a"] * 500 + ["b"] * 500

pipe = make_pipeline(
    ColumnTransformer(
        transformers=[
            ("one-hot", OneHotEncoder(), ["D"])
        ],
        remainder="passthrough",
    ),
    RandomForestRegressor(),
)

print(cross_val_score(pipe, df, y, cv=5, scoring="neg_mean_squared_error"))
```

Comment: I tried your code and it doesn't seem to work. I added an example of transformed_X, which is an array of floats.

Comment: The code does work: copy-and-paste this code, run it, and you should see a vector of 5 floats printed. If the code doesn't work: be specific. Did this exact code give the same error? Did you change something? Are you running a version of scikit-learn other than `1.2.0`?

Comment: The code does work. When I tried it just now, it worked, even after changing the fake dataset you had to my dataset, and changing to my categorical features. I'm not sure why it didn't seem to work before, maybe I had changed something else without noticing it. Thanks, @Alexander L.Hayes :)